# UITableView scrollToRow is animated while animated parameter is false

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation, swift3

I have a UITableView with lots of ( about 12000 ) items.
I jump to bookmarks using `scrollTo`:

```
line = 1234 // bookmark address
let index = NSIndexPath(row: line, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: index as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

The point is this scroll is sometimes with animation and sometime without!

Comment: animation is scroll, or flash?